# Presentation of wreath product $G=S_3 \wr S_3$ of symmetric groups. What is the isomorphism type of $G/[G,G]$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory, wreath-product

I'm trying to answer the first part of a group theory question as revision for an exam that goes as follows;

> Let $G = S_3 \wr S_3$, the permutational wreath product of two symmetric groups of degree three. Give a presentation for $G$ and determine the isomorphism type of $G/[G, G]$.

I'm not sure how to go about finding generators for the wreath product itself.

> Is there a method for combining the generators of the symmetric groups to form generators for the wreath prouct?

Any pointers would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can't find generators, then you haven't got much hope of answering the question! The obvious generating set consists of generators of the two natural subgroups isomorphic to $S_3$, giving four generators in all. For these,you could take for example:  $(1,2,3)$, $(2,3)$, $(1,4,7)(2,5,8)(3,6,9)$, and $(4,7)(5,8)(6,9)$.

Comment: I would like to know what a presentation of the Wreath product of two groups given by $\langle X\mid R\rangle$ and $\langle Y\mid S\rangle$ looks like in general, if possible; I might ask a question on MSE about it.

Comment: @DerekHolt, do you know of such a presentation? I'm aware of, say, [this](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=G.+Baumslag%2C+Wreath+products+of+finitely+presented+groups%2C+Math.+Z.+75+%281961%29%2C+22-28.&btnG=#d=gs_qabs&p=&u=%23p%3DGopC3KZ6cGsJ), but, for some reason, I can't get access to it; my institution is not subscribed :(

Comment: @shaun I have answered the question.

Comment: Thank you, @DerekHolt.

Comment: I found [this](https://berstein2015.wordpress.com/2015/06/15/wreath-products-and-finiteness/) on a presentation for $$\langle X\mid R\rangle\wr\langle Y\mid S\rangle.$$

Comment: dear @Shaun, I am a few years late on this, but, if you would like, I can send you a pdf of the paper you have linked to in your comment above.

Comment: Dear @AtticusStonestrom, yes, please! My university email address is si17471@essex.ac.uk.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a presentation of $S_3 \wr S_3$. Note that $a,b$ generate the top $S_3$ factor, and $x,y$ generate one of the three factors of the base group, the other two being $\langle x^a,y^a \rangle$ and $\langle x^{a^2},y^{a^2}\rangle$, where $x^a = a^{-1}xa$.
$$\langle a,b,x,y,\mid  a^3,b^2,(ab)^2,x^3,y^2,(xy)^2,
 [x,x^a],[y,x^a],[x,x^{a^2}],[y,x^{a^2}],
 [x,y^a],[y,y^a],[x,y^{a^2}],[y,y^{a^2}],  
 [x,b], [y,b] \rangle.$$
A routine calculation from the presentation shows that $G/[G,G] \cong C_2 \times C_2$, but it is not hard to show that directly.

PS: In fact the four  relators $[x,x^{a^2}],[y,x^{a^2}],[x,y^{a^2}],[y,y^{a^2}]$ are redundant. The fact that $\langle x,y \rangle$ commutes with $\langle x^{a^2},y^{a^2} \rangle$ follows from the fact that $\langle x,y \rangle$ commutes with $\langle x^{a},y^{a} \rangle$ by conjugating by $b$.